antd time picker component right to left
My html is dir="rtl"
which makes the TimePicker component from antd to not behave correctly
instead of hours in the left and minutes in the right, its reversed.

as you can see the minutes are in the left instead of the right
this is the code:
const StartDateTime = ({ value, onChange }: startDateTime) => (
  <TimePicker
    dir="rtl"
    format="HH:mm"
    className="w-full"
    value={value}
    onCalendarChange={(time) => onChange(time as any)}
  />
);

I tried adding dir="rtl" which doesn't do anything

The TimePicker doesn't receive the dir attribute, you want to modify the time-panel directly.
You can think about the following two separate components as the TimePicker:

Input Field:



Time Panel (This is the one you refer to):



The problem is that the TimePicker creates multiple divs (so the Time Panel will be able to have its CSS modified without affecting the Input Field).
So modifying the TimePicker directly won't work. You can think about it as the container of both the Input Field and the Time Panel. And we want to modify the Time Panel, not its container.
The Time Panel is the container of the hours and minutes columns.

I went into the Inspect Tools and checked which class the TimePicker Panel has that can be modified to change the direction. The answer is the ant-picker-time-panel class.
So you can add some CSS to modify this class as the following:
.ant-picker-time-panel {
  direction: ltr;
}

CodePen

Thanks. i added the time panel to have direction ltr which is correct, but now it opens only on the left side of the input and not on the right side. i tried using absolute/relative, and using placement attribute from antd which nothing works
